# Что ставить после слов «в переводе...»?

Tags: пунктуация

В переводе с английского «цветок».
В переводе с английского — цветок.
В переводе: цветок.

Как быть? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В переводе с английского — цветок.

или

В переводе с английского означает «цветок».

Двоеточие нельзя.

Пример:

Страйкбо́л (от англ. strike — удар, ball — шар) — командная, военно-тактическая игра.